# Select comma separated records from table along with user image

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Table :  **frei_session**

```
id  username        accountId   status  status_mesg

14  Sumit Bijvani   50          0       I am available
16  Dilip Borad     49          1       I am available
15  Karan Bijvani   51          1       I am available
```

Table :  **users**

```
accountId    friends      userImage

49           50,52        49.jpg
50           49,52,51,44  50.jpg
51           50           51.jpg
```

I have 2 tables, **frei_session** have records of online users and **users** table have data of users and friends of them separated ID by comma.

I want to retrieve data from **frei_session** table based on **friends** column of **users** table.

**For Ex**

If `user 49` is online, I want **Output** like below

```
id  username        accountId   status  status_mesg        userImage

14  Sumit Bijvani   50          0       I am available     50.jpg
```

Because User 50 and 52 is friend of User 49 but now only User 50 is online

I have tried following query. but it show me wrong userImage.

```
SELECT  b.*, a.userImage
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN frei_session b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.accountID, a.friends) > 0
         INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  accountID, username, MAX(id) id
            FROM    frei_session
            GROUP   BY accountID, username
        ) c ON b.accountID = c.accountID AND
                b.username = c.username AND
                b.id = c.id
WHERE   b.status = 0 AND
        a.accountID = 49
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/763ce/1)

Comment: This because of the duplicate values in the frei_session for each `accountid, username` use `MIN` instead of `MAX` will give you the output you are looking for: [**like this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/763ce/9). Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result from the `frei_session` is the friend of `user (a)` that's why it does not contain the image of your friend but the image of the user you are trying to search. So in order for you to get your friends image, you need to join it to another `user (d)` so you can get the correct image from the `frei_session` table.

```
SELECT  b.*, d.userImage
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN frei_session b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.accountID, a.friends) > 0
         INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  accountID, username, MAX(id) id
            FROM    frei_session
            GROUP   BY accountID, username
        ) c ON b.accountID = c.accountID AND
                b.username = c.username AND
                b.id = c.id
        INNER JOIN users d
          ON b.AccountID = d.AccountID
WHERE   b.status = 0 AND
        a.accountID = 49
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/763ce/10)

Comment: You are genius man. I am speech less. Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: JW when I use `accountId = 50`. it is not working http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/763ce/19

Comment: yes because there are no `accountid` (*50's friend*) in `frei_session` that has a status of `0`. Take note that his friends are `49,52,51,44`.

Comment: try `a.accountID = 51` and it will have one result.

Answer (score 2):

By normalizing your tables you can do all this with basic JOIN operarions. Please take a look at [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) as your schema violates all rules of proper database design.

- `friends` contains more than a single value and therefore violates
  the first normal form.
- `status_mesg` depends on `status` and
  therefore violates the second normal form.

Comment: no problem. I'm convinced that reading these article will help you more than just workarounds.